# PieSeries in a listboxItem

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a listboxitem whose datatemplate contains a pieseries. The listbox is bound to the class having a dictionary member. I want to bind that dictionary member to the pieseries. I have tried couple of ways, but it did not work. it is generating blank pieseries. The pieseries datacontext is being set to the datacontext of the listboxitem and still it is not working.

let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after long struggle just by writing a converter to do the calculation which were there in the dictionary.